Surjective geometric morphisms and comonadic adjunctions
I recently realized that although I know how to prove the equivalence of all the usual characterization of surjective geometric morphisms, and establish the surjection–embedding factorization, I didn't actually have a nice motivation for considering the particular definitions. I'll focus on the characterization of a surjective morphism $f$ as $f^* \dashv f_*$ being a comonadic adjunction here.
What would be a reasonable motivation to consider such a concept? In other words, how would a mathematician reasonably come up with this notion, when developing the theory of geometric morphisms from scratch? (If it is the actual history of discovery then even better, but just a plausible fairy tale is enough.) Does it fall naturally out of trying to produce the surjection–embedding factorization? If we look at the finite case $\operatorname{PSh}(2) \to \operatorname{PSh}(1)$, we can see that the comonad is $(A, B) \mapsto (A \times B, A \times B)$, and a coalgebra structure is exactly an isomorphism $A \cong B$. This suggests that a coalgebra structure here is somehow ensuring that if the points $p, q$ are mapped to the same point by the map, then the stalk should be isomorphic. So when we take the topos of coalgebras of $f^*f_*$ we get exactly the sheaves on the image.
Now comonadic maps are mentioned a little bit later in Elephant, on descent of indexed categories. I think this might be adapted to our case here, but the arguments don't quite work out. It goes like this: Suppose $f : E \to F$ is surjective, then given a sheaf $X$ on $E$, we can try to make it descend on $F$ by considering the pullback of toposes
$$
\begin{matrix}
\bullet & \overset{q}{\longrightarrow} & E \\
\llap{p}\downarrow && \downarrow \rlap{f} \\
E & \underset{f}{\longrightarrow} & F
\end{matrix}
$$
Then for compatibility we need a map $q^* X \to p^* X$ (it will be guaranteed to be an isomorphism by the other conditions). This is equivalent to a map $X \to q_* p^* X$, which becomes a map $X \to f^* f_* X$ by Beck–Chevalley. There's our coalgebra! Now the rest of the descent conditions define all the coalgebra equations. So this looks like the perfect motivation if it were true. However I don't think Beck–Chevalley holds generally in this case.
Maybe it suffices to have one commutative square satisfying the Beck–Chevalley condition, not necessarily the pullback (which is a bit difficult to describe anyway, like the products of locales are difficult)? Maybe we can directly see how $X \to f^* f_* X$ is the needed map, without using Beck–Chevalley which is a bit too complicated?

I'm not sure if this is the kind of answer you're looking for, but my impression is that the (geometric surjection, embedding) factorisation system is given by the (inclusion, surjection) factorisation system in the proarrow equipment of toposes in §4 of Wood's Proarrows II, which gives one explanation for where these two classes come from.

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what exactly you're looking for, too. Are you trying to understand why you would call a comonadic geometric morphism "surjective"? Or how you would notice that geometric morphisms satisfying some other characterization of surjectivity happen to be comonadic? Or why you would start to consider comonadic geometric morphisms in the first place?

@KevinCarlson I'm wondering about the latter two.

It seems to me that if you're a founder of topos theory in about 1968 and you're constantly thinking about these newfangled geometric morphisms and reading or hearing Beck's new monadicity theorem, you almost can't help but notice that the inverse image of a geometric morphism is awfully close to being comonadic.
Indeed, since the comonad $f^*f_*$ associated to any geometric morphism is left exact, the crude monadicitiy theorem applies: you know $f^*$ is comonadic if and only if it's conservative, insofar as it has a right adjoint. In fact, I wouldn't be too surprised if you already knew such a crude comonadicity result before Beck's theorem.
So I think geometric morphisms with comonadic inverse image come up quite naturally in a world where geometric morphisms, adjunctions, monads and comonads, and monadicity theorems are all being developed by a heavily overlapping group of people and all in the space of a decade (if I'm remembering the history right, Kan didn't give the definition of adjunction till 1959.)
